# Using narrow function in consult

Tags: consult

```
;; Optionally configure the narrowing key.
;; Both `<` and `C-+` work reasonably well.
```

I don't get how, am able to search. If I press `C-x C-f` to find a file, then a try to `C-+` or `<`, but nothing happens. How do I use this function+

Comment: I found it to be working in consult-org-heading.

Answer (score 3):

Is `C-x C-f` bound to `find-file` for you? If so, that's not a `consult` command, and so it doesn't support narrowing (although not all `consult` commands support narrowing).

Try `C-x b` (`consult-buffer`), then hit `<` (or whatever `consult-narrow-key` is set to), and then you can press `f` to narrow to files, `m` for bookmarks, etc.

This is covered in the README [here](https://github.com/minad/consult#narrowing-and-grouping) and [here](https://github.com/minad/consult#virtual-buffers).